# Applying rules which use the current time to vary the Moment.js locale display formats

Tags: momentjs

I'm new to moment.js and am running some test cases for a project I'm working on. One of the requirements is to show event times to a user based on rules relative to the current time. The rules are as follows:

1. If the current time and the event time are in the same day for the user, then only the time should be displayed.
2. If the current time and the event time are in the same year, then the day, month and time should be displayed (i.e. the year should be omitted)
3. If neither of the rules above apply then the full date and time should be displayed.

Working through some examples:

**A. Consider the current UTC time is 2016-04-07T12:00:00 and I want to show an event at 2016-04-07T01:22:44 UTC.**

i. To a user in London I will display a "Europe/London" timezone:

Converting the current UTC to Europe/London gives 07-Apr-16, 13:00:00
Converting the event UTC to Europe/London gives 07-Apr-16, 02:22:44

The Europe/London times are on the same day and so, based on the rules, we will display: 02:22:44

ii. To a user in the Los Angeles I will display a "America/Los_Angeles" timezone:

Converting the current UTC to America/Los_Angeles gives 07-Apr-16, 05:00:00
Converting the event UTC to America/Los_Angeles gives 06-Apr-16, 18:22:44

The America/Los_Angeles times are on different days, so rule 1 does not apply. The events are in the same year though and so we will display: 06-Apr, 18:22:44

**B. For this example consider the current UTC time is 2016-04-07T12:00:00 (as before) and I want to show an event at 2016-01-01T02:33:55 UTC.**

i. To a user in London I will display a "Europe/London" timezone:

Converting the current UTC to Europe/London gives 07-Apr-16, 13:00:00
Converting the event UTC to Europe/London gives 01-Jan-16, 02:33:55

The Europe/London times are on different days, so rule 1 does not apply. The events are in the same year though and so we will display: 01-Jan, 02:33:55

ii. To a user in the Los Angeles I will display a "America/Los_Angeles" timezone:

Converting the current UTC to America/Los_Angeles gives 07-Apr-16, 05:00:00
Converting the event UTC to America/Los_Angeles gives 31-Dec-15, 18:33:55

Neither rule 1 or 2 apply as the events are in different years so we will display: 31-Dec-15, 18:33:55

I've worked through the above, ending up with code as follows (this is from my jsFiddle test code):

```
  if (currentMomentForZone.format("DD-MMM-YYYY")==eventMomentForZone.format("DD-MMM-YYYY")) {
    // If the event and current day are the same just show the time
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "Event Time: "+ eventMomentForZone.format("HH:mm:ss") + "<BR/>";    
  } else if (currentMomentForZone.format("YYYY")==eventMomentForZone.format("YYYY")) {
      // If the event is in the current year then don't bother to include the year
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "Event Time: " + eventMomentForZone.format("DD-MMM, HH:mm:ss") + "<BR/>";   
  } else {
    // Different year, so show the full date time
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "Event Time: "+ eventMomentForZone.format('DD-MMM-YY, HH:mm:ss') + "<BR/>"; 
  }
```

The complete test code is in a JS Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sbssw/xy5bv3bt/ - this works well enough but doesn't currently take account of the locale setting for date display.

My question then is twofold, firstly how should I best apply the locale settings to my rules above? The available selections under http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ don't include a format which omits the year, which seems a simple thing and so I'm wondering how I might best acheive this?

Secondly, is there a better way to do this than the process I've used in the jsfiddle example? Typically I need to display many hundreds of events, with a few thousand in some more rare cases, so I need an optimised solution and my lack of experience with moment.js is causing me to wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Are you always working with the user's *local* time zone? If so, then there's no need to use moment-timezone or the `tz` function at all.  Moment can work in UTC mode or local mode without any additional time zone support.

Comment: @MattJohnson When you say local time zone do you mean that determined from the browser? The user's time zone will be saved as part of a user's preference setting, which is stored server side so I'm wondering how I might use that without moment-timezone? Could you clarify this for me? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I meant local from the browser.  If you're saving it the user's preferences as an IANA time zone identifier, then, *yes* you do need moment-timezone and the `tz` function.  However you don't need it for UTC.  You can simply use the `utc` function on moment itself.  You also don't need to use `format` during the comparison process, as there are functions for returning individual date parts that are more efficient.  I'll post a more complete answer later.

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes, I'm looking at storing the IANA time zone identifier serverside, along with a locale, and using it in the browser using moment.js alongside using Noda Time for server side rendering, it seems to be an approach which will work well. I look forward to your further guidance, thanks.

Comment: Yes, those pair well.  Be sure to read up on how to keep them both updated with the same TZDB data though! For Noda, [use NZD files](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/tzdb.html).  For moment, each tzdb release we create a new moment-timezone release.  So currently, you should have moment-timezone 0.5.3-2016c, and tzdb2016c.nzd.